# MVC/Razor DisplayAttribute when using inheritence

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm setting up a bunch of Razor pages for maintaining reference tables. The basic structure in the data context is this:

```
public class RefTableBase {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}

public class UserType: RefTableBase {}

public class ReferenceType: RefTableBase {}
```

The scaffolded Razor pages work correctly there. However, When I have a class that calls the derrived tables, the pages don't display what I expect.

```
public class SomethingImportant {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public int UserTypeId {get;set;}
    public virtual UserType UserType {get;set;}

    public int ReferenceTypeId {get;set;}
    public virtual ReferenceType ReferenceType {get;set;}
}
```

When the index.cshtml page is scaffolded, the tables headers look like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.SomethingImportant>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserType.Value)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReferenceType.Value)</th>
```

But when the page is actually rendered in the browser, the column headings show

```
Id    Name    Value    Value
```

When what I want is:

```
Id    Name    User Type     Reference Type
```

I've tried using DisplayAttribute on the members within the class, but it didn't work.

```
public class SomethingImportant {
    // ...........
    [Display(Name="User Type")]
    public int UserTypeId {get;set;}
    public virtual UserType UserType {get;set;}
    // ...........
}
```

Outside of skipping the inheritence and actually setting the DisplayAttribute for each and every class in the derived classes, is there any way I can get it to show how I want?

Comment: I would need to be `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserType)` and the `DisplayAttribute` applied to `UserType`

Comment: UserType property in SomethingImportant does not have disply attribute

Comment: just delete the .value from these two last lines. (ie model.UserType.Value --> model.UserType)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply put the Display attribute on the properties in question:

```
public class SomethingImportant {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public int UserTypeId {get;set;}
    [Display(Name="User Type")]//here
    public virtual UserType UserType {get;set;}

    public int ReferenceTypeId {get;set;}
    [Display(Name="Reference Type")]//and here
    public virtual ReferenceType ReferenceType {get;set;}
}
```

And remove calling `.Value` on the view.

```
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)</th>
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserType)</th>
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReferenceType)</th>
```

If you need `.Value` and it's a property of that class, you can put the `Display` attribute on those properties instead.

Comment: Of all the various combinations I tried... This worked perfectly! Thank you so much!